# Unity - How to save and load lists (Binary Saving and Loading)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

I'm trying to figure out how you would save & load list of data. I've gotten my code to work with single data but unsure of how a list one would work. I have a Character class so that means I can have multiple characters and I would like to save each of those character's hp, mana etc.

```
//SaveManager class that I can call from anywhere to save and load
public static class SaveManager 
{
    //SAVE
    public static void Save(Character c)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Save.save";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        PartyData data = new PartyData(c);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Close();
    }

    //LOAD
    public static PartyData Load()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Save.save";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            PartyData data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as PartyData;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Save FIle not Found");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

PartyData class is what I'm using to save the Character data to.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PartyData
{
    public int hp;

    public PartyData(Character cParty)
    {
        hp = cParty.HP;       
    }
}
```

Character class that contains stats etc

```
public class Character
{
   public int HP { get; set; }

   public int Mana { get; set; }
}
```

And then finally I have the CharacterParty class that I attach to a gameobject, this class contains multiple characters and calls the Save and Load functions:

```
public class CharacterParty : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] List<Character> characters;

    public List<Character> Characters
    {
        get
        {
            return characters;
        }
    }

    public void SaveParty()
    {
        SaveManager.SaveMC(characters[0]);
    }
    public void LoadParty()
    {
        PartyData data = SaveManager.LoadMC();

        characters[0].HP = data.hp;

    }
}
```

Now for testing purposes I tried saving & loading just the character's hp at index 0 and it works but now I wanna save a list of multiple character's hp and mana etc. I just don't know how the list would work with serialization saving and loading. My code probably needs a little bit of change to get the list working so I hope someone can help me out with an example.

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) class - this is Unity's built-in utility for JSON.

Also with this you can serialize any class without [System.Serializable]

Save:

```cs
// Parties list
List<PartyData> parties = new List<PartyData>();

// Add your parties here
// First argument is an instance of a class or any other object
// If second argument set to true, it makes JSON more human-readable
string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(parties, false);

// .. saving the file
```

Load:

```cs
// .. loading the file

// First argument is the JSON
List<PartyData> parties = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<PartyData>>(json);

// .. do stuff with the list
```

**EDIT:**

If you really want to use BinaryFormatter, then this is for saving:

```cs
List<PartyData> parties = new List<PartyData>();
// .. add parties
formatter.Serialize(stream, parties)
```

For loading:

```cs
List<PartyData> parties = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as List<PartyData>;
// .. do stuff
```

**SECOND EDIT:**

This one should work.
You would do something like that:

```
// Save class
[Serializable]
public class Save
{
    public List<PartyData> parties;
    // .. add other stuff here
}

// For loading
try
{
    // Deserializing the save
    Save save = (Save)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    // .. do stuff with other data if you added some
    foreach (PartyData data in save.parties)
    {
        // .. do stuff with data
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // .. can you just acnowledge... E
    // Oopsie! An error occured. The save file is probably COWWUPTED
    Debug.LogWarning($"An error occured while loading the file: {e}");
}

// For saving
List<PartyData> parties = new List<PartyData>();
// .. add parties by calling parties.Add(party_here);
// Creating a save
Save save = new Save();
// Adding parties to save
save.parties = parties;
// Serialize to a file
formatter.Serialize(stream, parties);
```

Comment: Json is insecure type of saving from what I have seen so far. People can just edit their save files through editing the text.

Comment: Kira, Binary one is also unsecure beacuse everyone can just edit anything is the file easy as in JSON afaik

Comment: I tested both, with JSON, you can clearly make out what is what with the values shown. But with Binary, if you open with like notepad you see weird symbols and and the class name like PartyData and words like hp from stat, but you don't see any values. It may not be perfect, I'm sure there is a way around it but JSON is still way too simple and insecure compared to binary.

Comment: I read that if you do use JSON, the best practice is to encrypt it a little. You would then have to convert it to a byte. I just don't know any examples that show saving as JSON then converting to byte. But anyway if I were to use JSON then I would have to do that, convert to byte, which I don't really know how to.

Comment: if your game is on android, just use PlayerPrefs - it is very safe. And also, you cannot convert it to byte beacuse it's two very different things. And you cannot see the value of HP beacute it's an integer, which means in bytes it will not be saved as a string but as a number.

Comment: Playerpref is also a bad practice, its mainly used for things like settings, like volume control etc. It is definitely not recommended for a medium - big size game. if you have like a couple variables then I guess its fine but mine has lots like hp, mana, strength, charisma and so on.

Comment: Thank you, I did that but it still doesn't work. I think I'm calling the method wrong. If you look at my CharacterParty class for Save and Load, how would you write that?. I put in a for loop but it doesn't seem to work, for load it throws object reference error

Comment: Check the answer again

Comment: @Kira, if this helpred you, please mark this as an answer. Thank you